# jQuery object, inconsistent global variables and AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm looking to get what I thought would be a simple script to run an AJAX call and keep various values stored to an object, but I cannot get the globals to remain consistent the way I would expect.

I've gone around in circles trying what I think is everything. As soon as I put the AJAX call in I can't get it to play nicely with the global variables. The `process` value is always `false` that way and the content never loads in.

```
ExtContent = function(){
    var self = this;
    this.init = function() {
        self.output = null;
        self.process = false;
    };
    this.request = function(url){
        $.ajax({
            type     : 'GET',
            timeout  : 10000,
            dataType : 'html',
            url      : url,
            passself : self,
            success  : function(response){
                this.passself.setoutput(response);
            },
            error    : function(req,response){
                if(response==='error'){
                    self.error=req.statusText;
                }
            }
        });
    };
    this.setoutput = function(data){
        this.output = data;
        this.process = true;
    };
    this.returnprocess = function(){
        return self.process;
    };
    this.returnoutput = function(){
        return self.output;
    };
    self.init();
};
```

`<div id="holder"></div>`

```
loadcontent = new ExtContent(); 
loadcontent.request('/test.html');

if(loadcontent.returnprocess()){
    $('#holder').before(loadcontent.returnoutput());
}else{
    $('#holder').before('FAILED');
}
```

I can't get the `process` to be `true` and the content to be stored in `output`.

Thanks.

Comment: Indent your code, no one will look at it like this

Comment: Sorry Stefanz. Thanks phillip for updating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite wrapping everything as a class/object, the jQuery `$.ajax` call is still an *asynchronous* operation. basically "You have ordered a pizza, then try to eat it before it arrives".

i.e. this orders it:

```
loadcontent.request('/test.html');
```

and this tries to eat it immediately:

```
if(loadcontent.returnprocess()){
```

The call to `setoutput` (i.e. the "Pizza delivery") happens long after these operations complete.

You need to add event handler properties to your class, or use deferreds+promises to wait for the data to arrive.

To use promises, just return the $.ajax result from `request`:

```
this.request = function(url){
    return $.ajax({
        type     : 'GET',
        timeout  : 10000,
        dataType : 'html',
        url      : url,
        passself : self,
        success  : function(response){
            this.passself.setoutput(response);
        },
        error    : function(req,response){
            if(response==='error'){
                self.error=req.statusText;
            }
        }
    });
};
```

and use it like this:

```
loadcontent.request('/test.html').done(function(){
    if(loadcontent.returnprocess()){
        $('#holder').before(loadcontent.returnoutput());
    }else{
        $('#holder').before('FAILED');
    }
 });
```

Or if you setup the return values correctly inside request:

```
loadcontent.request('/test.html').done(function(){
    $('#holder').before(loadcontent.returnoutput();
}).fail(function(){
    $('#holder').before('FAILED');
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This makes absolute sense I just wasn't thinking about that. Just clicked straight away. Much appreciated TrueBlueAussie!

Answer (score -2):

Maybe this can help you

```
this.setoutput = function(data){
    // 'this' here, is refering 'setoutput' function, not ExtContent,
    // so ExtContent.process != ExtContent.setoutput.process

    // this.output = data;
    // this.process = true;
    self.output = data;
    self.process = true;
};
```

Comment: This is both incorrect and misleading. `this` will be the calling scope (usually the class instance in this code "object") as they use a copy of `self` stored on the ajax context. The actual problem is trying to use Async data before it is returned.